# First time DM - Is it a good idea to use stock photos / images?

Tags: dnd-5e, art

I don't think I'm particularly good at detailed poetic descriptions and I'm worried my imagination could be a bit on the slow side.

I was thinking I could use something like a quick and dirty powerpoint presentation showing some concept art / stock photos of various locations and NPC. Not only for the players but also for me to figure out what to describe if I get stuck.

Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. I see you're already a member of a few other Stacks but I'll mention taking the [tour] anyway. Unfortunately whether something is a good or bad idea isn't something we'll be able to answer as it's simply a matter of opinion and not something we field on this Q&A site. Such things are better left to forums so can I suggest checking out [our curated list of recommended forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/14878) and asking this question on one of those instead.

Comment: @1600hp One downside could be that maybe they take the image too literally and focus on some unimportant stuff, like in a harbor:"I open that barrel on the left" etc.

Comment: @Blckknght it's in person. Character sheets on paper. Maps might be digital though if they're not simple to draw.

Comment: Hi @Paprik. This is an interesting question but I agree in its current form it is opinion-based. I think if you change the question slightly to ask about if people have used stock images and how effective were they it could be answered. That requires some expertise and experience to answer, which is kind of our jam.

Comment: Have you tried things like dungeon tiles, 3d terrain, or virtual tabletops?

Comment: Closing a question as a "duplicate" of a "closed" answer means that **no-one will ever be able to add to that knowledge base**, unless the question is re-opened - like in this case, because an anwer has been accepted.  Using down-voting in punitive way is not what down-voting is intended for. When several seasoned contributors organise to purposely down-vote a question instead of explaining things first, it is just rude and petty. It is also bullying. Next time please explain first.

Comment: @Orc'sPlunder This question was closed as opinion-based (not a duplicate, which would show a link to the duplicate) and doesn't currently have any downvotes. You don't have sufficient reputation here to see those specific details. The fact that it has an accepted answer has no bearing on it's closed status. If it had been downvoted (which it wasn't), there is no reason to believe it was some conspiracy of seasoned contributors - people are allowed to downvote as they please. TLDR: Nothing you claim appears to have happened; what are you talking about?

Comment: @Orc'sPlunder questions are closed when they don't fit the format and reopened when they do. I don't see any obvious reason this question wouldn't be reopened if it were workshopped to rephrase as the question you asked - and you should've proposed that rather than asking a new question to get around the closed status.

Comment: @Carcer I think that editing this to ask for the pros/cons would be changing the question too much such that we should just ask it as a new one anyway. It would be invalidating all the answers here, which is a pretty strong sign!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### It's OK to use photos when they're relevant, but I recommend using them for *yourself* rather than for your players.

The focal point of a storytelling game is inevitably going to be telling of stories. As DM, you will be responsible for narrating events, describing locations and characters, providing action-packed descriptions of fight scenes, and more.

Showing a picture is fine, when a specific situation calls for it-- I often sketch out diagrams for my players, and make analogies to things they've seen in real life. But I do those things to *support* my storytelling, not to *replace* it. Immersion will primarily come from things that you, yourself, provide to the table. I do *not* recommend preparing a slideshow for players to sit through in one go-- that's the opposite of engaging.

A relatively small photo, even of something dramatic (like the Grand Canyon or an erupting volcano) will only go so far to inspire your players' imaginations and help them get into the game. They'll glance at a picture for a moment, but can't interact with it at all.

So if you'd like to use pictures, what I'll recommend instead is that you get your photos but use them alongside your notes to help you remember what features you want to describe, and how. Look at the photo and describe what you see, and you get the best of everything! Similarly, jotting down notes about memorable features of locations, NPCs, and situations can help keep details fresh in your mind when you need them.

If you're worried about including enough details when you have to improvise, you can always write down a framework of things you want to be sure to mention: apparent age, gender, clothing, a memorable physical feature, or things like that. That makes it a lot easier to think of specific elements in the moment.

And, ultimately, you will get better at DM-ing through experience. Even if you stumble sometimes at first, you will improve as long as you keep at it. You won't get the same improvements if you outsource your narrative duties to photographs.

Comment: +1 for "But I do those things to support my storytelling, not to replace it." Great point/advice.

Answer (score 9):

## Presenting Is a Bad Idea

Presenting a list of photos to a group of people who gathered to play a game will result in immediate boredom. Powerpoint, in particular, is the worst way to keep the attention of your audience.

## Get Inspiration from Photos Instead

Getting inspiration from photos (real or rendered) is a great idea and most likely almost everyone does it. So, instead of presenting these photos to your group, why not load up the images in your laptop/phone and simply describe to them what you see.

## You Don't Need to Be Poetic

Just be descriptive. *"You're in a grassy field. The sun sets behind the mountains. The sky is red. You see clouds in the distance. It's going to rain soon."* There's nothing poetic about these sentences, yet they are more than enough to immerse your players. The same applies to anything (NPC, monsters, etc).

Comment: I like the section about not needing to be poetic. Even if you want to be, it gets old when mundane things need to be described. A good poetic description should have an intentional, dramatic purpose, and will often benefit from advanced planning anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you are young because if you had been through as many education and work-related PowerPoint presentations as I have, you would know that your players would rather eat their own eyeballs than sit through another one.

Don't sell yourself short. The odds are that you are no better or worse than average at descriptions (poetic or otherwise - not that I've ever had a DM describe things in verse) and imagination. You are just talking with friends - just tell them what they need to know to make decisions for their characters.

Props are fine but actually learn to DM first.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR-- The idea is not without precedent, but it's not a great idea.

### Published Modules Sometimes Use Canned GM-Materials

I've been GMing long enough that I remember the original *Tomb of Horrors* 1e module, which included pictures to show to players at various locations within the Tomb-- I think there have been a few others that did something similar.

There was also a long trend of including "Boxed Text" to be read aloud as a description to players for each location.

So the idea of canned, prepared descriptions, either visual or verbal, is not without precedent.

### I've Also Occasionally Prepared Material Like This Myself

Usually not for a location, though-- usually for a specific item or object, if it was an image.  I did go through a long phase where I thought boxed text was just *the thing to do* for writing up my own modules.

### What I Learned Was:

Having a picture or a set block of text tended to remove spontaneity from both myself (as I read the text) and from the players (because it was obvious I was reading from text.)  Eventually I learned that riffing on it was a better way to go.

Similarly but not the same, for images, I learned that showing someone a picture put a very concrete image in their mind.  This initially seems like a good thing-- it seems like having five players with five identical images is what you want.  But unless you're showing them **exactly** what you want them to see (as with the *Tomb of Horrors* pictures) you now have five players with the same slightly wrong image in their heads.

If that drawbridge doesn't look right, or if you forgot you wanted a sally port there and this picture doesn't have it, your "do-over" is exponentially harder than saying, "Oh, crap, I forgot, there's a sally port on each side," because your players' minds already have that particular castle in mind.

### Also, It's More Fun To Improvise

This of course is highly subjective, not a law of nature, but... it's just more fun.  Part of the fun of GMing is bringing my spontaneity in contact with the players' to see what happens.

If your players are *at all* sympathetic and helpful, they'll bear with you as you stretch and develop those descriptive muscles.